# SOQL: prevent SOQL injection - best practices

Tags: soql, security, bestpractice

I have a query string that is as follows(no bulkification required)...

```
 String qryString = 'SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE (IsDeleted = false and Name like \'%' + searchText+ '%\')';
```

**searchText** is a text input field. This code is prone to SOQL Injection because of the apostrophe. So how to make it safe?

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a [Salesforce help article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.216.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm?search_text=soql%20injection) that addresses this..

The main point's are:

- Avoid using dynamic SOQL where possible, instead use static queries and binding variables
- If you must use dynamic SOQL, use the `escapeSingleQuotes` method to sanitize user-supplied input.

Here is an example of moving from a dynamic query to a static query with binding variables:

> **Dynamic Query**
>
> ```
> public class SOQLController {
>     public String name {
>         get { return name;}
>         set { name = value;}
>     } 
>     public PageReference query() {
>         String qryString = 'SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE ' +
>         '(IsDeleted = false and Name like \'%' + name + '%\')';
>         queryResult = Database.query(qryString);
>         return null;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> **Static Query**
>
> ```
> public class SOQLController { 
>     public String name { 
>         get { return name;} 
>         set { name = value;} 
>     } 
>     public PageReference query() { 
>         String queryName = '%' + name + '%';
>         queryResult = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE 
>            (IsDeleted = false and Name like :queryName)];
>         return null; 
>     } 
> }
> ```

Comment: Can you add a bullet point to say "use simple bind variables" in dynamic SOQL? The [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) isn't great but binding works for dynamic SOQL as well for simple cases and offers the same SOQL injection defence benefits as it does in static SOQL.

Comment: Yes it does nick. Thanks. @KeithC can you please explain what is  "use simple bind variables". Does it mean using static query?

Comment: @MnZ No it means you can bind a variable such as a string or a date or a decimal into the dynamic SOQL using the `:myVarName` syntax. You can't (directly) bind a dotted expression such as `mySob.MyField__c`; instead you first have to assign that to a simple variable `String myVarName = mySob.MyField__c` and then bind the simple variable.