# How can I rewrite this function to avoid SQL injection

Tags: apex, soql, soql-injection

I am new to Salesforce and Apex, my Java experience is ancient as well. I was trying to escape every parameter in this function but am still getting:

```
Apex classes should escape variables merged in DML query (rule: Security-ApexSOQLInjection)
```

Apex code:

```java
  private static List<Activity__c> getAllActivitySObjectsByJunction(String byField, String idField, String tableName, String recordIdField, String recId){
    String query = 'SELECT Id FROM Activity__c WHERE ('+ byField +' IN (SELECT '+idField+' FROM '+tableName+' WHERE '+recordIdField+' = \''+ String.escapeSingleQuotes(recId) +'\')) ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 200';
    return Database.query(query);
  }
```

Example usage:

```java
List<SObject> acts = getRelatedActivitySObjectsByJunction('Contact__c', 'ContactId', 'OpportunityContactRole', 'OpportunityId', recId);
```

I would like ideally to be able to use syntax as follows:

```java
    List<Activity__c> acts = new List<Activity__c>();
    for(Activity__c act: [SELECT Id FROM Activity__c WHERE :idField = :recId ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 200]){
      acts.add(act);
    }
    return acts
```

But I am not sure how to do it if field comes from variable, how would I go about improving first version so it does not throw  injection warning or if it is possible to rewrite using second example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SOQL: prevent SOQL injection - best practices](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41266/soql-prevent-soql-injection-best-practices)

Comment: it doesnt work, cant use bind variables as field names

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use bind variables or field tokens, you can wrap every potentially vulnerable string in `String.escapeSingleQuotes()`.

E.g.:

```
byField = String.escapeSingleQuotes(byField);
```

A better way would be to refactor your method so that it takes a [field token](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_field_tokens.htm) instead of just a string of the field's name.